MacOS keeps waking up from sleep every 2 seconds until the battery is drained
Lately I've noticed that I cannot leave my MacBook Pro unplugged since macOS will keep waking it up until the battery is drained. I close the lid, thinking it will go to sleep, but clearly that's not happening. I've tried several including enabling hibernate mode (hibernatemode=25) but even then it wakes up??
I've also tried disabling various other features I found online but nothing seems to help. Today I was checking the output of pmset -g log and indeed I see it wakes up every 2 seconds. It's the same few lines every 2 seconds. Based on this log any idea what could be the issue?
Spec: MacBook Pro, 2019, macOS 14.4.1 (23E224)
2024-06-18 00:09:44 +0100 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Sleep notifications: [AppleIntelFramebuffer driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(1938 ms)] [DSB1 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(658 ms)] [DSB4 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(658 ms)] [DSB0 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(656 ms)] [AppleHPMIECS driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 2)(812 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(936 ms)] [AppleHPMIECS driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 2)(1094 ms)] [AppleUSBVHCIBCE driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(309 ms)] [RP01 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(1013 ms)] 
2024-06-18 00:09:44 +0100 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(575 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(575 ms)] [ADIO driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(590 ms)] [XHC3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(652 ms)] [ATY,Boa driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(444 ms)] [DSB0 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(503 ms)] [PEG1 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(1019 ms)] [DSB1 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(658 ms)] [DSB4 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(657 ms)] [DSB0 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(656 ms)] [AppleHPMIECS driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 2)(810 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(936 ms)] [AppleHPMIECS driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 2)(1093 ms)] [AppleUSBVHCIBCE driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(315 ms)] [RP01 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(1011 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(547 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(546 ms)] [ADIO driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(561 ms)] [XHC3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(652 ms)] [ATY,Boa driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(438 ms)] [AppleUSBVHCIBCE driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(313 ms)] [RP01 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(1004 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(541 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(541 ms)] [ADIO driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(583 ms)] [XHC3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(652 ms)] [ATY,Boa driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(431 ms)] [AppleUSBVHCIBCE driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(309 ms)] [RP01 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(1002 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(546 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(547 ms)] [ADIO driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(608 ms)] [XHC3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(653 ms)] [ATY,Boa driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(432 ms)] [AppleUSBVHCIBCE driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(307 ms)] [RP01 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(1012 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(550 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(549 ms)] [ADIO driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(591 ms)] [XHC3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(652 ms)] [ATY,Boa driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(442 ms)]           
2024-06-18 00:09:53 +0100 Assertions            PID 122(powerd) Released InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:08  id:0x0xd0000985c [System: No Assertions]          
2024-06-18 00:09:53 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:8%) 21 secs   
2024-06-18 00:09:55 +0100 Wake Requests         [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2024-06-18 02:09:53 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=33467 wakeAt=2024-06-18 09:27:42] [*process=powerd request=CSPNEvaluation deltaSecs=1076 wakeAt=2024-06-18 00:27:50] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=4095 wakeAt=2024-06-18 01:18:10 info="com.apple.alarm.user-invisible-com.apple.calaccessd.travelEngine.periodicRefreshTimer,543"]           
2024-06-18 00:09:55 +0100 PM Client Acks        Delays to Sleep notifications: [com.apple.apsd is slow(1026 ms)] [com.apple.bluetooth.sleep is slow(1568 ms)]           
2024-06-18 00:10:13 +0100 Assertions            PID 301(mDNSResponder) Created MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00009866 [System: No Assertions]          
2024-06-18 00:10:13 +0100 Assertions            PID 301(mDNSResponder) Released MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00009866 [System: No Assertions]          
2024-06-18 00:10:14 +0100 Assertions            PID 122(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00009868 [System: PrevIdle]          
2024-06-18 00:10:14 +0100 DarkWake              DarkWake from Standby [CDN] : due to EC.ACDetach/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:8%) 8 secs    
2024-06-18 00:10:14 +0100 HibernateStats        hibmode=25 standbydelaylow=10800 standbydelayhigh=86400                               rd=219 ms     
2024-06-18 00:10:14 +0100 WakeTime              WakeTime: 1.806 sec             

2024-06-18 00:10:14 +0100 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Sleep notifications: [AppleIntelFramebuffer driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(1938 ms)] [DSB1 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(658 ms)] [DSB4 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(658 ms)] [DSB0 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(656 ms)] [AppleHPMIECS driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 2)(812 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(936 ms)] [AppleHPMIECS driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 2)(1094 ms)] [AppleUSBVHCIBCE driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(309 ms)] [RP01 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(1013 ms)] 
2024-06-18 00:10:14 +0100 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(575 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(575 ms)] [ADIO driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(590 ms)] [XHC3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(652 ms)] [ATY,Boa driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(444 ms)] [DSB0 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(503 ms)] [PEG1 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(1019 ms)] [DSB1 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(658 ms)] [DSB4 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(657 ms)] [DSB0 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(656 ms)] [AppleHPMIECS driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 2)(810 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(936 ms)] [AppleHPMIECS driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 2)(1093 ms)] [AppleUSBVHCIBCE driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(315 ms)] [RP01 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(1011 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(547 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(546 ms)] [ADIO driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(561 ms)] [XHC3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(652 ms)] [ATY,Boa driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(438 ms)] [AppleUSBVHCIBCE driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(313 ms)] [RP01 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(1004 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(541 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(541 ms)] [ADIO driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(583 ms)] [XHC3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(652 ms)] [ATY,Boa driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(431 ms)] [AppleUSBVHCIBCE driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(309 ms)] [RP01 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(1002 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(546 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(547 ms)] [ADIO driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(608 ms)] [XHC3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(653 ms)] [ATY,Boa driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(432 ms)] [AppleUSBVHCIBCE driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(307 ms)] [RP01 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(1012 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(550 ms)] [UPSB driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(549 ms)] [ADIO driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(591 ms)] [XHC3 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(652 ms)] [ATY,Boa driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(442 ms)]           
2024-06-18 00:10:22 +0100 Assertions            PID 122(powerd) Released InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:08  id:0x0xd00009868 [System: No Assertions]          
2024-06-18 00:10:22 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:7%) 21 secs   
2024-06-18 00:10:24 +0100 Wake Requests         [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2024-06-18 02:10:23 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=33438 wakeAt=2024-06-18 09:27:42] [*process=powerd request=CSPNEvaluation deltaSecs=1046 wakeAt=2024-06-18 00:27:50] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=4065 wakeAt=2024-06-18 01:18:10 info="com.apple.alarm.user-invisible-com.apple.calaccessd.travelEngine.periodicRefreshTimer,543"]           
2024-06-18 00:10:24 +0100 PM Client Acks        Delays to Sleep notifications: [com.apple.apsd is slow(1114 ms)] [com.apple.bluetooth.sleep is slow(1568 ms)]           
2024-06-18 00:10:42 +0100 Assertions            PID 301(mDNSResponder) Created MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00009871 [System: No Assertions]          
2024-06-18 00:10:42 +0100 Assertions            PID 301(mDNSResponder) Released MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00009871 [System: No Assertions]          
2024-06-18 00:10:43 +0100 Assertions            PID 122(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00009874 [System: PrevIdle]          
2024-06-18 00:10:43 +0100 DarkWake              DarkWake from Standby [CDN] : due to EC.ACDetach/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:7%) 8 secs    
2024-06-18 00:10:43 +0100 HibernateStats        hibmode=25 standbydelaylow=10800 standbydelayhigh=86400                               rd=222 ms     
2024-06-18 00:10:43 +0100 WakeTime              WakeTime: 1.802 sec                                                                   

Output of pmset -g:
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 lidwake              1
 lowpowermode         0
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 proximitywake        1
 standby              1
 standbydelaylow      0
 ttyskeepawake        1
 highstandbythreshold 50
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 hibernatemode        25
 displaysleep         60
 womp                 0
 networkoversleep     0
 sleep                0 (sleep prevented by mds_stores)
 tcpkeepalive         1
 halfdim              1
 acwake               0
 disksleep            0


Have you turned off Wake on Lan? It looks like there's something on the local network that's waking it.

I think it's about the EC.ACDetach/Maintenance darkwakes. Can you try disabling darkwakes?

The output of pmset -g can help with diagnosis. Please add that to question.

@gilby, I have added the pmset output now

@benwiggy, yes Wake on Lan is disabled

@hym3242, how would I disable darkwakes?

@laurent sorry I posted that comment without much thought —— i thought pmset had an option about darkwake but no.

I always set tcpkeepalive to 0. That removes one cause of wakes.

This is an "answer" because it is long, not because it solves the problem.
On a 2016 MacBook for which I believe sleep settings are similar to 2019 MBP, I used:
pmset -g   (Battery)
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 lidwake              1
 autopoweroff         1
 standbydelayhigh     7200   2 hours (not a day)
 autopoweroffdelay    14400
 proximitywake        0      to stop wakes due to nearly iPhone, etc.
 standby              1
 standbydelaylow      7200
 ttyskeepawake        1
 hibernatemode        3      25 doesn't help
 gpuswitch            2
 powernap             0
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 highstandbythreshold 50
 displaysleep         5
 sleep                5      Not 0
 tcpkeepalive         0      Most important to prevent network wakes.
 halfdim              1
 acwake               0
 disksleep            1

